# Web Service Returning 19x1 instead of just 1 (vTiger CRM)

Tags: web-services, api, vtiger

I'm customizing vTiger CRM and creating a web service and have noticed that it returns the object as this:

```
Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [result] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sessionName] => 695f5450544fb7cf4
        [userId] => 19x1
        [version] => 0.22
        [vtigerVersion] => 6.0.0
    )
)
```

The userID is just 1 and not 19x1 so I'm trying to figure out why this gives me 19x1. It also does it when passing an object other places. I'm thinking it is just a format I'm either not decoding right (the web services recommend http_client and Zend JSON decode but I've only got CURL and regular json_decode on the server) or just a format I'm not familiar with.

Can anyone guide me as to why this is being returned like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its actually Webservice Entity id and ObjectId, (UserModule Id **X** User id)

From Vtiger Wiki

> objectTypeId 'x' objectId objectTypeId - Id of the object type. This
>   is generated uniquely for each entity supported by Web service API and
>   returned in the result of describe operation as idPrefix. objectId 
>   id of object in database. This is a globally unique id for objects of
>   the given entity

You will get all the Web service Entity ids from this table : *vtiger_ws_entity*

https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/510:Webservice_reference_manual#Id_Format

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$id_arr= explode('x', $request->userId);
$id= (int) $id_arr[1];
```

I think they pas integers with a prefix